# WxPython: deriving wx.ListItem but wx.ListCtrl only returns old class

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl

I've  got a small issue with derived classes, namely `wx.ListItem` with `wx.ListCtrl`. I succesfully derived `wx.ListItem` as a `MediaItem`, the code is not finished but you get the point:

```
class MediaItem(wx.ListItem):
    def __init__ (self, fullname):
        wx.ListItem.__init__(self)
        self.fullname = fullname
        self.filename = os.path.basename(fullname)
        # snap...

    def getFullname(self):
        return self.fullname
```

`wx.ListCtrl` gladly accepts that because of Pythons duck philosophy. But now the problem is that using the method `wx.ListCtrl.GetItem(index)` returns a `ListItem`, not `MediaItem`. Python complained about `wx.ListItem` not having an attribute `getFullname`.

Casting objects seems to be the wrong way to approach the solution. This probably has nothing to do with the problem, but I paste the offending line as is as well:

```
filename = self.filelist.GetItem(event.GetIndex()).getFullname()
```

Where `self.filelist` is a `wx.ListCtrl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I should just suck it up, and regress to the suboptimal manual bookkeeping. When done tastefully, it's not a big deal but I had higher hopes for wxPython.

Supposedly (from what I searched and collected) the issue is with the proxy nature of wxPython class base. Were they written in pure Python, or I coded in C++, this would have worked well. But now the polymorphism of objects fails because of limitations in the design: the native C++ wx class won't get anything but a `wx.ListItem` and it will certainly only return a `wx.ListItem` back to wxPython.

My "solution" thus is to derive `wx.ListCtrl` instead of `wx.ListItem`, store needed information and control the appearances there.